# Lazy load partial resultset or conditional resultset

Tags: jpa, lazy-loading, one-to-many

I am working on a Java EE project that uses JPA for persisting the data to database. I have the following two persistence entities (Action and Notification) defined.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Action")
public class Action{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="businessAction", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<Notification> notifications;

    //***************SOME OTHER STUFF**********************
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Notif")
public class Notification{

    @Column(name="NOTIF_DATE")
    private Date notifDate;         

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="FOR_ACTION_ID")
    private Action action;

    //***************SOME OTHER STUFF**********************
}
```

From the code it can be seen that I am lazy loading the Notifications for Action. In my scenario there are thousands of notifications for a Action and I don't want to load all those notifications. I wanted to load only specific notifications based on the notifDate in Notification.

Can anyone please suggest me a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect use case for filters if they are supported by your JPA provider.

For example, in Hibernate you could simply define a [filter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html) on the `notifications` collection and enable it by default for all `Session`s in the application. Depending on which framework you use for transaction management, you can add an interceptor/hook that enables the filter when transactions are started.